# Google ignoring our page title / meta desc after moving to SPA (SSR) architecture

Tags: seo, search-results

Ever since we moved our site to a SPA architecture (SSR based, Vue+Nuxt), google chose to completely ignore our carefully written page titles and meta descriptions. Obviously we checked the sources, all html tags are correct in the right places, but google chose to completely ignore / change them. (other search engines show correct titles/descs).

Weirdly, in most cases, when it comes to page titles, it uses parts of of what we provide, but moves the kw which is used as first word, and creates a suffix from it. 
This might explain us jumping up and down in serps for our 3 main keywords.

Here is an example:
One of our pages, where 'Fotowoltaika' is the main KW, and title we set is 
"Fotowoltaika - kalkulator opłacalności w 2020 roku"

Google result:

[image: Google result]

Meanwhile, in source of this very page:

[image: source of the live page]

Page itself:
https://fotowoltaikaonline.pl/kalkulator

On this particular page, description is preserved, but on dozens other pages they're completely ignored. Which is quite common on all sites, when google thinks it's smarter than content writers, but I've never seen Google changing titles like this. In most cases google-changed titles do not make any sense grammatically, for sure affecting our CTRs.

Has anyone ever come across a situation like this? Any help, hits, ideas would be greatly appreciated..